# Measures of predictive power of attributes in data mining

Tags: data-mining, feature-selection

What are the most widely used measures of predictive power of attributes in scoring models?

**Motivation**: I have a lot of attributes, more than I can study by myself and I want to select somehow the most promising ones. Is IV a good criterion for that? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: There is a little [science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) about this...

Comment: @mbq: Most of the techniques mentioned in the link are time consuming. I'm looking for methods with complexity proportional to the size of the data. IV satisfies this condition, but I have some concerns. I think that it is a bit odd that it takes into account only the relative risk. The number of occurences is not used.